# Informatica error : RowType=-4(error but dropped due to abort)

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am getting the below error:
    There is an error in the port [NEXTVAL]: 
    The default value for the port is set to: ERROR(<> 
    [ERROR]: transformation error   ... nl:ERROR(u:'transformation error')).

```
2015-11-27 08:00:45 : ERROR : (582188 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Oracle_BI_DW_Server) : 
node01_ : TT_11023 : An error occurred converting data in the port [NEXTVAL]. The row was dropped.

2015-11-27 08:00:45 : ERROR : (582188 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Oracle_BI_DW_Server) : 
node01_ : TT_11021 : 
An error occurred moving data from the transformation RECON_SEQ_GEN: to the transformation FILTRANS.

2015-11-27 08:00:45 : ERROR : (582188 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Oracle_BI_DW_Server) : 
node01 : CMN_1086 : RECON_SEQ_GEN: Number of errors exceeded threshold [1].

2015-11-27 08:00:45 : INFO : (582188 | TRANSF_1_1_1) : (IS | Oracle_BI_DW_Server) : 
node01_ : CMN_1053 : : Rowdata: 
( RowType=-4(error but dropped due to abort) Src Rowid=1186281 Targ Rowid=1186281
NEXTVAL (ROW_WID:Int:): "(NULL)"
)
```

Comment: Make sure the data type of the NEXTVAL port in filter transformation is integer

Comment: "An error occurred converting data in the port [NEXTVAL]" < check what are the datatypes of both ports and adjust.